# Python dataframes: issue when attempting to group by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to group by multiple columns and return the sum of select columns in my dataframe. I was able to do this by only grouping by one column

```
df_sum = df.iloc[:, 27:].groupby(df['id']).sum().reset_index()
```

I am successfully grouping by `id` and summing the values from column 27 to the end of my dataframe. However, when I try to group by multiple columns using

```
df_sum = df.iloc[:, 27:].groupby(df['id', 'year']).sum().reset_index()
```

I get an error

```
KeyError: ('id', 'year')
```

I have been able to group by multiple columns before by using something like

```
df.groupby(['id', 'year'])['some col name'].nunique().reset_index()
```

I tried using this type of format

```
df.groupby(['id', 'year'])[df.iloc[:,27:]].sum().reset_index()
```

But it also does not work as I get another error

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I'm currently a bit confused on how I can get this to work. I feel like I must be overlooking something relatively simple since I am able to get it to work for grouping by one column. I am just struggling to find a way to get it to work when grouping by multiple columns.

Comment: can you post your dataframe?

Comment: Remove the letters `df` inside groupby. Your code should be `df_sum = df.iloc[:, 27:].groupby(['id', 'year']).sum().reset_index()`

Comment: @moys now I just get an error `KeyError: 'id'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether *id* column is within the subset "from 27-th column to the end".

I suppose that this column is at some **earlier** position in your *df*.

## Another solution to try

Generate the target list of columns:

```
cols = df.columns[27:]
```

Then use it in your instruction:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'year'])[cols].sum().reset_index()
```

Note that *cols* itself is a **list**, but in the instruction above
it must be "enveloped" with another pair of square brackets.

Comment: Both the `id` and `year` columns are before the 27th column in my dataframe. So I see what you are saying but why would `df_sum = df.iloc[:, 27:].groupby(df['id']).sum().reset_index()` work then? It is only when I try to group by a second column I run into the key error.

Comment: Sorry I misread your response originally. Your solution works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Putting the columns you want to group by inside a list will solve the issue.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])['marks'].sum()
```